# Is there a way to use several cygwin terminals?

Tags: shell, terminal, cygwin

Is there a way to use several cygwin terminals? I can only open one at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open a Cygwin terminal
2. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> or Right click on the top bar | New to open a new terminal